# Logarithmic tiks not showing in pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

I have a very simple logarithmic plot, but for some reason I can't manage to show the ticks in the vertical axis. Why is this happening and is there a way to know a priori how to set the axes so that logarithmic ticks always show?

```
\documentclass[border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}         
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        xlabel=DOFs,
        ymin=1e-15, ymax=10,
        xmin=100, xmax=10000,
        width = 7cm,
        legend style={at={(0, 0.)}, anchor=south west,draw=none},
    cycle list name=black white,
        every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.west)},xshift=-30pt,rotate=90}
        ]

    \addplot [RoyalBlue, thick, mark=o, mark options={scale=1.,solid, RoyalBlue}] table{%
            121 0.08945684062706045
            341 0.0036813848097262576
            561 0.00034635822751205646
            881 2.0512221130767817e-05
            1301 7.797318160808208e-07
            1821 2.125368998262977e-08
            2441 4.5746964051472774e-10
            3161 8.682927671779316e-12
            3981 1.4744125484712826e-13
            4901 3.91582540186572e-15
    };
   \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example works fine here, up to date TeX Live 2017, `pgfplots` version 1.15.

Comment: There isn't enough space to label them all.  If you increase the height, more will become visible.  I would just list the tick values.

Comment: While I did add an answer, I'm not really sure if it answers your question, as you seem to say that you don't get any ticks at all (which was the reason behind my first comment, above).

Answer (score 4):

With your code I get yticks at `10^0`, `10^(-5)`, `10^(-10)` and `10^(-15)`. If you want yticks at every order of magnitude, you can add either `ytick distance=10^1` or `ytickten={-15,-14,...,1}` to the `axis` options. That will also give you minor ticks, and makes things a bit cramped:

[image: all ticks]

If you want to remove the minor ticks, set `subtickwidth=0pt` in the `axis` options.

`ytickten={-15,-13,...,1}` might be better:

[image: output with ytickten={-15,-13,...,1}]

```
\documentclass[border=20pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} % use color
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}         
    \begin{loglogaxis}[
        xlabel=DOFs,
        ymin=1e-15, ymax=10,
        xmin=100, xmax=10000,
        width = 7cm,
        ytick distance=10^1,
        % ytickten={-15,-13,...,1},
        % subtickwidth=0pt
        ]

    \addplot [RoyalBlue, thick, mark=o, mark options={scale=1.,solid, RoyalBlue}] table{%
            121 0.08945684062706045
            341 0.0036813848097262576
            561 0.00034635822751205646
            881 2.0512221130767817e-05
            1301 7.797318160808208e-07
            1821 2.125368998262977e-08
            2441 4.5746964051472774e-10
            3161 8.682927671779316e-12
            3981 1.4744125484712826e-13
            4901 3.91582540186572e-15
    };
   \end{loglogaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, "distance."  I kept searching for interval.